# ipv6 route add with next hop fails

Tags: linux, ipv6, route

I'm trying to add an ipv6 route on machine B to subnet behind next hop A:

```
2:2:2::2/64 +---+ 192:168:2::1/64      192:168:2::10/64 +---+
       -----| A |---------------------------------------| B |
            +---+                                       +---+
```

The next hop (`192:168:2::1`) is reachable (ping succeeds), yet I cannot add it as a next hop in an ipv6 route:

```
(B):~ > sudo ip -6 route add 2:2:2::/64 via 192:168:2::1
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
```

Is it possible to get more details about which argument in the `ip route add`-command is invalid and why? How can I add a route for an ipv6 subnet that is not locally available?

These are the interfaces on machine B:

```
(ANDEVVM22):~ > ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 3000::c066:def9/64 scope global
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::90af:efff:fe88:2e1b/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth100: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::102e:2eff:fe41:4887/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 500
    inet6 192:168:1::10/64 scope global
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 500
    inet6 192:168:2::10/64 scope global
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are playing in unallocated bogon space?  Generating ULAs, or getting a prefix from an ISP, or even the documentation prefix, would not conflict with the internet.

Comment: This is only used in a test setup, disconnected from the internet. So I assume it doesn't really matter which exact addresses I use?